# Upload form field file using redux saga call

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-saga, saga

I am uploading a file in the body as `form-data`. Using `ajax` it works fine but when I try to do the same in `redux-saga`, it does not work and fails. What am I doing wrong?

In ajax,

```
let upload = ajax.post(PathHelper.apiPath + '/create/text').field('file', file);
    upload.end((err, response) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log('Error Encountered', err);
      }
      if (response) {
        const imageResponse = response.body;
        console.log('imageresponse: ', imageResponse);
      }
    });
```

Here is my saga code:

```
export function* fetchText(text) {
const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('file', text.data);
  console.log('formData: ', formData);
  try {
    const options = {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
      },
      body: formData
    };
    const response = yield call(fetchJson, PathHelper.apiPath + '/create/text', options);
    console.log('response: ', response);

  } catch (err) {
    console.log('Error saving your image', err);
  }
 }
```

Comment: Looks ok. What is your `fetchJson` function? Does it return a promise (as it should do)?

Answer (score 0):

> when I try to do the same in redux-saga, it does not work and fails

`Redux-saga` itself is about perform asynchronous action, fired on some `redux` event, so firstly, maybe `put` action is omitted - usually saga intercepts `request`-like action and creates `success` action after operation is completed. In that case, there should be `redux`-reducer, which will accept API call result and apply it somethere on UI component.

Secondly, uploading files requires live HTML form with `enctype="multipart/form-data"`, and `FormData` object should be attached to original form. See details here: http://researchhubs.com/post/computing/javascript/upload-files-with-ajax.html